# Swype remove special characters?

Tags: swype

Is there a plugin or any other way to use swype but force it to auto-replace special characters like `č` with `c`,  `ž` with `z` etc. ?

As currently Swype is predicting words - for example: `"Španija"` and it would be great if it would be replaced with `"Spanija"` as it would then have 160 characters in SMS message instead of 70, like when using special characters.

Comment: What if you added these words to your dictionary?

Comment: ..then I would have to do that for all the words in the dictionary that have special characters, sadly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the message application, click the menu button and enter Settings, select "Text input mode" and change the option from Automatic to GSM Alphabet. When you type in the message it appears as special characters but when the message is sent it is automatically converted to normal text.

Comment: I have actually read this before posting question here. I have triwd it again, and I see that it is working. It actually replaces special characters with "regular" english characters, BUT so far, I can see it is only working on stock messaging applications. I have tried, I have set it, and used Pansi messaging program that I use, and it is still sending special characters within the message. I will mark the answer as correct, but effectively I still need to find an answer for my Pansi messaging app :/